# keyerror while migrating in python

Tags: python, django, database-migration, migrate, keyerror

i am trying to run but it is not working

```
python manage.py migrate
```

its showing error

```
    Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions, signup
Running migrations:
  Applying signup.0002_auto_20210511_2201...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\VAISHNAVI SHUKLA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\VAISHNAVI SHUKLA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 413, in execute        
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\VAISHNAVI SHUKLA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv      
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\VAISHNAVI SHUKLA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\VAISHNAVI SHUKLA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 89, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\VAISHNAVI SHUKLA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 244, in handle 
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "C:\Users\VAISHNAVI SHUKLA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\VAISHNAVI SHUKLA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\VAISHNAVI SHUKLA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 227, in apply_migration  
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Users\VAISHNAVI SHUKLA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 116, in apply
    operation.state_forwards(self.app_label, project_state)
  File "C:\Users\VAISHNAVI SHUKLA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 92, in state_forwards
    state.models[app_label, self.model_name_lower].fields[self.name] = field
KeyError: ('signup', 'students')
```

what does keyerror mean. I have been trying to solve it. I tried deleting migrated files but after running `makemigrations` again it made no difference and said `No changes detected`

these are the contents of migration file 0001_intial.py

```
from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='faculty_signup',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('firstname', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
                ('lastname', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
                ('coursecode', models.CharField(max_length=20)),
                ('registration', models.CharField(default=123, max_length=100)),
                ('classnumber', models.CharField(max_length=20)),
                ('pwd', models.CharField(default=123, max_length=100)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='signup_table',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('firstname', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
                ('lastname', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
                ('yearofjoining', models.IntegerField()),
                ('registration', models.CharField(default=123, max_length=100)),
                ('pwd', models.CharField(default=123, max_length=100)),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

and here is 0002

```
from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('signup', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='students',
            name='pwd',
            field=models.CharField(default=123, max_length=100),
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='students',
            name='rpwd',
            field=models.CharField(default=123, max_length=100),
        ),
    ]
```

please help if possible, this error has been troubling me for a while

Comment: Show the contents of the migration files `signup.0001` and `signup.0002` (In your app `signup` in the directory `migrations`, these files will be present with names like `0001_<something>`, etc.)

Comment: I have added the two files please have a look

Comment: The table `students` was not created with `0001_intial.py`. Only `signup_table` and `faculty_signup` were created. The second migrationfile cannot find this table because it does not exist.

Comment: Do you use [django-extensions](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)? You can reset your db and recreate all models. It is easier instead of deleting your database manually.

Comment: i made changes in my 0002 file and it is working properly now. Thank you so much for helping :))